# Is there a way to concatenate variable number of columns using CONCAT(table_name(col1, col2, col3,.....)) in redshift?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am executing a sql query using a python script which passes a parameter with variable number of columns and do a JOIN with another table based on these columns.  Is there a way to concatenate variable number of columns ?
my query is

```
DELETE FROM INPUT_SCHEMA.INPUT_TABLE A 
using TARGET_SCHEMA.TARGET_TABLE_NAME B 
where 
A.COMMON_COL1=B.COMMON_COL1 
and A.COMMON_COL2=B.COMMON_COL2
```

Here I am joining with 2 columns, but ideally it is a variable number, in future I might add 10 more columns. And the columns list is passed through python

Comment: This should be easy in Python. Edit the question and show your actual Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
    select col1|| ' ' || col2
    from table
```

or use `concat`

```
select concat(col1, col2)
from table
```

Comment: my query is 
DELETE FROM INPUT_SCHEMA.INPUT_TABLE A
using TARGET_SCHEMA.TARGET_TABLE_NAME B
where A.COMMON_COL1=B.COMMON_COL1 and A.COMMON_COL2=B.COMMON_COL2

Here I am joining with 2 columns, but ideally it is a variable number, in future I might add 10 more columns. And the columns list is passed through python

Comment: @dev . . . This answers the question that you asked, and the answer looks correct to me.  If you have another question, ask it as a *question* not a comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added it in the question. Thanks